# Render CSS on Server side rendering ReactJs

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, express, server-side-rendering

I'm developing server sider rendered reactjs application.Everything works fine but I'm having an issue  ,that is take time to render css in first load (only content loading with html.after seconds css load).I tried [Isomorphic-Style-Loader](https://github.com/kriasoft/isomorphic-style-loader) as well.

**Client.js**

```
import './../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import './styles/css/main.css';

const initialState = fromJS(window.__INITIAL_STATE__) ;
const Store = createStore(
  reducers,
  initialState,
  applyMiddleware(thunk.withExtraArgument(axiosInstance))
);

hydrate(  
  <Provider store={Store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div>
        {renderRoutes(Routes)}
        <Footer/>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>  
  </Provider>,
  document.querySelector('#root')
);
```

**Server.js**

```
import renderer from './helpers/renderer';

const app = express();
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  const store = createStore(req);  
  const promises = matchRoutes(Routes, req.path)
    .map(({ route, match }) => {

      var parts = req.path.split("/");
      var lastSegment = parts.pop() || parts.pop();
      return route.loadData ? route.loadData(store, lastSegment) : null;
    })
    .map(promise => {
      if (promise) {        
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          promise.then(resolve).catch(resolve);
        });
      }
    });
  Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
     const context = {};
    const content = renderer(req, store, context);
    if (context.url) {
      return res.redirect(301, context.url);
    }
    if (context.notFound) {
      res.status(404);
    }   
    res.send(content);    
  });
});

app.listen(SERVER_PORT, () => {
  console.log('Listening on port '+SERVER_PORT);
});
```

**Renderer.js**

I tried to load all css file from rendere.js.but it's not helped and html body part disappeared when page reload.

```
export default (req, store, context) => {
  const content = renderToString(
    <Provider store={store} >
      <StaticRouter location={req.path} context={context}>
        <div>{renderRoutes(Routes)}</div>
      </StaticRouter>
    </Provider>
  );

  const helmet = Helmet.renderStatic();
  return `<!doctype html>
    <html lang="en"> 
      <head>
      <link rel="shortcut icon" href="fav.png">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">        
        ${helmet.title.toString()}
        ${helmet.meta.toString()}            
        </head>
      <body>
      <base href="/" />
        <div id="root">${content.toString()}</div>
        <script>
          window.INITIAL_STATE = ${serialize(store.getState())}
        </script>

        <script src="bundle.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
  `;
};
```

Comment: Try adding a `hidden` CSS class to body when doing SSR and remove that CSS class in renderer's `constructor`.